# Use Google Apps Script to identify "pasted characters" in a Google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've done a little bit of research in the google documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph), but really don't know what to specifically look for so this is more of an "is this possible" question.

I'd like to use Google Apps Script to evaluate a google document to see if portions of text have been "pasted in". For example, I'd like to know if a student copies a paragraph of text from a website (or any source) and pastes it into the google document.

If it is possible to identify "pasted text", is it also possible to identify the 'source'? For example, is the source the existing google document (moving text from one place to another) VS an external source (website or other document)?

If this is possible, can you explain a "big picture" approach for getting started?

Thanks!
Mr. Benrud

Comment: There's no such thing as 'pasted text' in Google Docs. When pasted, the plain text or any other formatting doesn't carry any details about its origins. All Google Apps run on Google Servers, not your computer, so you are pretty much limited to a small set of functions that Google makes available to you as a public API.

Comment: If you need to check for plagiarism, there are other tools for doing this

Comment: I was thinking about measuring the # of characters added between saves as a way to alert me of large chunks of information be added.

Comment: I think that the question is too broad for this site. Consider to post this on the Google Apps Script Community.

Comment: @I'-'I: That will occur on Aug 2019. There are still 10 months to use the referred community on its current space.

Comment: @I'-'I please checkout https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MartinHawksey/posts/daKt4gNQM29